# Is there a way to move the Abernathy cat with console commands?

Tags: fallout-4, mods, cheats

So basically I want to bring their cat with me to my settlement. I've already moved the Abernathys via console commands and it worked fine. This cat however is **very** stubborn. I first tried simply teleporting it but then the cat runs all the way back. So I then added it to the players faction, made it command-able and movable as a settler. Every time I click the new place and hit enter I check by hitting move again and the menu hasn't changed and my settlement is still an option as well as Abernathy farm. I don't know what the code is that keeps it there or if I can ever move her but if anyone knows any console commands for this that would be appreciated. I don't mind getting a mod to do this but the success rate with mods so far is 60/40 on everything else I'm doing.

Comment: Does it have to be _this_ cat? You can get cats in your other settlements if you have the wasteland workshop dlc.

Comment: I suspect that the cat has a script that makes it return to the vault as per the vanilla game. It lives in the vault and I expect it's tied to it since it's part of a quest.